# Is it possible to select from multiple tables without DB:Raw?

Tags: laravel

Some noob question about Laravel's query builder.
I'm trying to translate that simple SQL query :

```
SELECT s.name, e.name, m.name
FROM sports as s, events as e, matches as m
WHERE s.name = 'Football'
```

Where sports -> events -> matchs have a 1 -> n relation

- Match has an event_id foreign key
- Event has a sport_id foreign key,
- Sport is root.

So the above select query with s.name = 'Football' gives :

```
+----------+-------------+----------------------+
| name     | name        | name                 |
-------------------------------------------------
|Football  | World Cup   |  England vs Germany  |
|Football  | World Cup   |  Argentina vs France |
| ...      | ...         |  ...                 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to translate it in a Laravel Query Builder query, without using DB:Raw, and I'm a bit confused as all examples shown in the doc start with DB:table(blabla), which seems to accept only 1 table as parameter.
So something like

```
$events = DB::table('sports as s', 'events as e')
->select('s.name', 'e.name')
->where('s.name', '=', 'Football')
->get();
```

says e.name is considered unknown.
I've read some answers here that were all using DB:Raw or some strange joins.

So...Do you guys know any Laravel's Query Builder elegant way to handle those queries? Or do I have to stick to DB:Raw?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a relation between sports, events and matches?

Comment: You're right, sorry I forgot to say that

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're trying to do is create a union between your three tables.

From http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#unions

```
$first = DB::table('users')
            ->whereNull('first_name');

$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereNull('last_name')
            ->union($first)
            ->get();
```

> The unionAll method is also available and has the same method
>   signature as union.

A join would be used if you wanted to query your matches table for a match then join the event the match was played at on with match_id = event_id for example.

Answer (score 2):

Well after wasting quite some time, I found out that :

- Using a SELECT WHERE on multiple tables instead of explicit JOIN is considered a bad practice, essentially for code readability.
- There's probably no way with Laravel's Query Builder to achieve what I wanted (the bad practice way) without using DB:raw
- That the correct way to solve my problem is :

  ```
  $events = DB::table('sports as s')
          ->join ('events as e', 'e.sport_id', '=' , 's.id')
          ->join ('matches as m', 'm.event_id', '=' , 'e.id')
          ->select('s.name as sname',
                      'e.name as ename',
                      'm.name as mname')
          ->get();
  ```

(Works fine at least)

- That you **MUST** alias the names in the SELECT when the fields names are identical, or you'll get just one column for all identical names (that's where I lost quite some time :) ).
- I tried with Yii framework and the "bad practice way" worked fine as well as the join method :

  ```
   $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
   ->select(['sport_name' => 's.name','event_name' => 'e.name'])
   ->from(['s' => 'sports','e' => 'events'])
   ->where(['s.name' => 'Football'])
   ->all();
  ```

I hope this will help someone else,

Bye.